# How to get data in UIPickerView from Webservices

Tags: xcode, uipickerview

I am new to Iphone and I am working on a application where I have to use UIPickerView. I am able to populate the UIPickerView statically, but now I have to get data from WEBSERVICES and populate them into Picker View.

Can you please tell me the step by step guidance.

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use `UIPickerView` delegate methods and one `MutableArray`.
Use `MutableArray` to store your webservice response and then use it in your `UIPickerView` delegate methods :

```
// number of component to display in the pickerview
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView 
    {
        return 1;
    }

// numbers of row is the total numbers of object store in your array

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
    {

        return [YourArray count];
    }

//display your title

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
    {
        NSString *obj = [YourArray objectAtIndex:row];
        return obj; 

    }

// on click whatever you want to do.
    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
    {

       // onClick i am displaying the picker value in my textview you can do as per your requirement.
                mytextview.text=[YourArray  objectAtIndex:row];

    }
```

Comment: ::- thnx for the reply but i have used these delegate. NSMutable arrye is also required to get value in UIPickerView statically.. but my question is, how to get response from the webservice to add the data in pickerview

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
// MARK: - Picker View Delegate & Data Source

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return yourArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return yourArray[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    textView.text = yourArray[row]
}
```